# How to access a variable between two State-full Widgets? - Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm new to Flutter and I'm trying to access a variable between two Statefull Widgets within **build** method but my approaches are not working.

I took help from this [how to access an object created in one stateful widget in another stateful widget in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46542768/how-to-access-an-object-created-in-one-stateful-widget-in-another-stateful-widge) but didn't work for me.

> Here's Error (Second Class):

```
bottomNavigationBar: new Material(
        child: new TabBar(
          controller: tabController,   //can't accessible 
            tabs: <Widget>[
              new Tab(
                icon: new Icon(Icons.account_balance),
              ),
              new Tab(
                icon: new Icon(Icons.wb_sunny),
              )
            ],
        ),
```

> Here's my First Class

```
class BottomNavBar extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _BottomNavBarState createState() => _BottomNavBarState();
}

class _BottomNavBarState extends State<BottomNavBar>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin /*used for vsync*/ {

  /*controller*/
  TabController tabController; //wanna access this to Second Class

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    tabController =new TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new TabBarView(
      children: <Widget>[
        new NewPage("1st"),
        new NewPage("2st"),
      ],
      controller: tabController,
    );
  }
}
```

> Here's my Second Class

```
class BottomNav extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BottomNavState createState() => _BottomNavState();
}

class _BottomNavState extends State<BottomNav> {

  //BottomNavBar _bottomNavBar=new BottomNavBar();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Drawer App"),
        elevation: TargetPlatform.android != null ? 0 : 5,
      ),
      body: new BottomNavBar(),
      bottomNavigationBar: new Material(
        child: new TabBar(
          controller: tabController,   //can't accessible 
            tabs: <Widget>[
              new Tab(
                icon: new Icon(Icons.account_balance),
              ),
              new Tab(
                icon: new Icon(Icons.wb_sunny),
              )
            ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: whats your error ?

Comment: First you create `BottomNav` > Inside `BottomNav` you create `BottomNavBar` > Inside `BottomNavBar` you create `tabController`.

You want to access `tabController` inside `BottomNav`, but the variable hasn't even been created yet. Your structure doesn't make sense.