# How to Call stateful widget(have form) method from another dart file?- Flutter

Tags: forms, flutter, dart, statefulwidget

I have a Form in Stateful Widget, in my stateful widget i validate my form with submit method.

In my app i'm showing that form in another page in another dart file.

My form is visible in new page and in appbar actions i'm calling submit method but i don't know how to call that submit method in new dart file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you questions is not validation logic, you can do it in callback 
I think your situation is you may use SnackBar when submit button clicked. you use SnackBar to show error and you do not want to repeat this logic in appbar.

The trick is use GlobalKey to keep YourFormState and call function inside YourFormState with key.currentState , so submit button and appbar action can call the same fucntion

```
final key = new GlobalKey<MyCustomFormState>();
...
appBar: AppBar(          
          title: Text(widget.title),
          actions: <Widget>[
            // action button
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.access_alarm),
              onPressed: () {
                key.currentState.validateform();
              },
            ),
          ]),
...
children: <Widget>[
        MyCustomForm(key: key),

... 

class MyCustomForm extends StatefulWidget {
  MyCustomForm({ Key key }) : super(key: key);
```

full working code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());
final key = new GlobalKey<MyCustomFormState>();

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}
var myCustomForm =  MyCustomForm();

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
      // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
      // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
      // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
      // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
          actions: <Widget>[
      // action button
      IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.access_alarm),
      onPressed: () {
        key.currentState.validateform();
      },
    ),
      ]),
      body: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: Column(
          // Column is also layout widget. It takes a list of children and
          // arranges them vertically. By default, it sizes itself to fit its
          // children horizontally, and tries to be as tall as its parent.
          //
          // Invoke "debug painting" (press "p" in the console, choose the
          // "Toggle Debug Paint" action from the Flutter Inspector in Android
          // Studio, or the "Toggle Debug Paint" command in Visual Studio Code)
          // to see the wireframe for each widget.
          //
          // Column has various properties to control how it sizes itself and
          // how it positions its children. Here we use mainAxisAlignment to
          // center the children vertically; the main axis here is the vertical
          // axis because Columns are vertical (the cross axis would be
          // horizontal).
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            MyCustomForm(key: key),
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}

class MyCustomForm extends StatefulWidget {
  MyCustomForm({ Key key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  MyCustomFormState createState() {
    return MyCustomFormState();
  }

}

// Create a corresponding State class.
// This class holds data related to the form.
class MyCustomFormState extends State<MyCustomForm> {
  // Create a global key that uniquely identifies the Form widget
  // and allows validation of the form.
  //
  // Note: This is a GlobalKey<FormState>,
  // not a GlobalKey<MyCustomFormState>.
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Build a Form widget using the _formKey created above.
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          TextFormField(
            validator: (value) {
              if (value.isEmpty) {
                return 'Please enter some text';
              }
              return null;
            },
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
            child: RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                // Validate returns true if the form is valid, or false
                // otherwise.
                validateform();
              },
              child: Text('Submit'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void validateform() {
    // Validate returns true if the form is valid, or false
    // otherwise.
    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      // If the form is valid, display a Snackbar.
      Scaffold.of(context)
          .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Processing Data')));
    }
  }
}
```

demo works with SnackBar 
[image]

Comment: Thanks Bro, Your Code is Working fine. I have 2 doubts. In MyCustomFormState class you removed _ (Underscore). 1st Doubt). Removing underscore will create problem in app performance? 2nd Doubt). We already using GlobalKey for FormState and now created another GlobalKey for MyCustomFormState, so using 2 GlobalKey will create any Problem. i don't know more about GlobalKey. I'm beginner in Flutter. Please Explain

Comment: MyCustomFormState is official example from google. I did not modify it. underline means private. no performance issue. there is no conflict with two different variable(key).

Comment: for detail , you can see this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46542768/how-to-access-an-object-created-in-one-stateful-widget-in-another-stateful-widge

Comment: Oh, Thanks bro. and i don't need Snackbar. I have Form in 1 dart file. In main dart file i'm showing my form. In Appbar i'm calling the submit button, that is in another dart file. so while calling that function it validator calls with null. This is my problem. now it resolved.

Comment: hi, i tried it but, it show below error
 ════════ Exception caught by gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture:
The method 'test' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: test()

Comment: sorry i wasn`t send the key to child , it works ,thanks man

Comment: This doesn't work: `Exception caught by widgets library: Multiple widgets used the same GlobalKey.`

Comment: Hi @chunhunghan could you help with my case. I have this: eventform.dart => appbar: evenformappbar.dart, body: eventformbody.dart. eventformbody.dart => child: eventformform. my save / submit button is in my eventformappbar.dart, and my submit function is in my eventformform.dart. how do i access the function in the eventformform.dart from eventformappbar.dart? please help. thankyou.

Comment: @MichaelRenoPratamaSetyawan, Need to reproduce, could you post your reproduce code to a new question and ping my name. thanks.

Comment: @chunhunghan how about we discuss this in a chat?

Comment: @chunhunghan https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64532591/flutter-call-form-save-function-from-another-file

Answer (score 1):

You can create VoidCallback final at the top of your another widget, that will trigger the action of the parent widget.

```
class FormWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FormWidgetState createState() => _FormWidgetState();
}

class _FormWidgetState extends State<FormWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
      //here goes your form and everything else
      SubmitButton(
        onClick: (){
          //perform the actions you need
        },
      ),
      ],

    );
  }
}

class SubmitButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final VoidCallback onClick;

  const SubmitButton({Key key, this.onClick}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onClick,
      child:Container(

        //your button
    ),
    );
  }
}
```