# Flutter call form save function from another file

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart

I have this event form, it's to create or edit events data. The save button is inside the app bar action, and the form is inside the body. In this project, I have all of the widgets in different files. How do I run the save function inside EventFormForm.dart when I tap the save button inside EventFromAppBar.dart?
This is the structure :

[image]

These are my codes :

EventForm.dart

```
class EventForm extends StatelessWidget {
  // Some Code

  // Some Const

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: EventFormAppBar(
// Some Params
),
      body: EventFormBody(
// Some Params
)
    );
  }
}
```

EventFormAppBar.dart

```
class EventFormAppBar extends PreferredSize{
  // Some Code

  // Some Const

  // Some Code

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
      // Some Code
      actions: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.save),
          onPressed: () {

          }
        )
      ]
    );
  }
}
```

EventFormBody.dart

```
    class EventFormBody extends StatelessWidget {
      // Some Code
    
      // Some Const
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return SafeArea(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: EventFormForm(
    // Some Params
    ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }

EventFormForm.dart
class EventFormForm extends StatefulWidget {
  // Some Code

  // Some Const

  @override
  EventFormFormState createState() => EventFormFormState();
}

class EventFormFormState extends State<EventFormForm> {
//
//
// Some Code
//
//

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Form(
//
// Some Code
//
);
}

saveForm() {
//
// Some Code
//
}

}
```

Tag @chunhunghan

Comment: Tag @chunhunghan

Comment: Share the code rather than images. I suggest reading: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Im so sorry, i will edit this @Ashok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run each files below 
Step 1: Use `final keyForm = GlobalKey<EventFormFormState>();` 
Step 2: Pass `keyForm` to `EventFormForm(key: keyForm)` 
Step 3: In `IconButton` call `keyForm.currentState.saveForm();`

```
IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.save),
          onPressed: () {
            keyForm.currentState.saveForm();
          })
```

working demo

[image]

full code

[image]

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'event_form.dart';
import 'event_form_form.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());
final keyForm = GlobalKey<EventFormFormState>();

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: EventForm(),
    );
  }
}
```

event_form.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'event_form_appbar.dart';
import 'event_form_body.dart';
class EventForm extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(appBar: EventFormAppBar(), body: EventFormBody());
  }
}
```

event_form_appbar.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'main.dart';

class EventFormAppBar extends PreferredSize {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(actions: <Widget>[
      IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.save),
          onPressed: () {
            keyForm.currentState.saveForm();
          })
    ]);
  }

  @override
  get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(50);
}
```

event_form_body.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'main.dart';
import 'event_form_form.dart';

class EventFormBody extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: EventFormForm(key: keyForm),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

event_form_form.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class EventFormForm extends StatefulWidget {
  EventFormForm({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  EventFormFormState createState() {
    return EventFormFormState();
  }
}

class EventFormFormState extends State<EventFormForm> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          TextFormField(
            validator: (value) {
              if (value.isEmpty) {
                return 'Please enter some text';
              }
              return null;
            },
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
            child: RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                saveForm();
              },
              child: Text('Submit'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void saveForm() {
    print("execute save Form");
    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      // If the form is valid, display a Snackbar.
      Scaffold.of(context)
          .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Processing Data')));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @chunhunghan, that is if all the widget is in 1 file. If I separate them into different files, where do I put the final key = GlobalKey<EventFormFormState>(); ? I've tried this method, put it in my EventForm.dart, and pass the key to EventFormAppBar.dart and EventFormBody.dart and then to EventFormForm.dart, but it didn't work. It gave me an error :  ════ Exception caught by gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════ The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture: The method 'saveForm' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: saveForm()

Comment: I have update each file. In your case , please rename variable  key to keyForm.

Comment: isnt the EventFormFormState a private member by default while creating the stateful class? @chunhunghan

Comment: if i have a list view builder for form, i am getting an error - Multiple widgets used the same GlobalKey.
can you guide on this?

Comment: @himeshp, need to reproduce, could you post reproduce code to a new question? thanks.

Comment: @chunhunghan - thanks for the reply, here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65856420/flutter-save-multiple-forms-data-from-a-another-widget