# how to use another class property in flutter/dart

Tags: flutter, dart

i have a calendar and i want to use its date property in another class i already tried to make object but that does not work
here is what i tried for instantiate

```
var myCalender = MyCalendar();
```

and in the class i want to say something like

```
Text('$myCalendar.date');
```

and here is my calendar class

```
    class MyCalendar extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _MyCalendarState createState() => _MyCalendarState();
    }
    
    class _MyCalendarState extends State<MyCalendar> {
      static DateTime date = DateTime.now();
      TimeOfDay timeOfday = TimeOfDay.now();
    
      Future<Null> selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
        final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
   //show date picker Entrances i did not copy those to make the code shorter for you :)
        if (picked != null && picked != date) {
          print('date is ${date.toString()}');
        }
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
            child: FlatButton(
          onPressed: () {selectDate(context);},
          child: Text('calendar'),
          color: Colors.blue,
        ));
      }
    }
```

and here is my main.dart  for global key

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}
final key = GlobalKey<State<CustomCalendar>>();
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Container(child: Text('data'),),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually trying to access a property of the *state* of MyCalendar rather than of MyCalendar itself. To expose the state you can refer to this answer [how to access an object created in one stateful widget in another stateful widget in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46542768/how-to-access-an-object-created-in-one-stateful-widget-in-another-stateful-widge) and implement it like this for example:

```
final key = new GlobalKey<_MyCalendarState>();

void test(){
  print(key.currentState.date.toString());
}

class MyCalendar extends StatefulWidget {
  MyCalendar({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyCalendarState createState() => _MyCalendarState();
}

class _MyCalendarState extends State<MyCalendar> {
  DateTime date = DateTime.now();
  TimeOfDay timeOfday = TimeOfDay.now();

  Future<Null> selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
    final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
      //show date picker Entrances i did not copy those to make the code shorter for you :)
    if (picked != null && picked != date) {
      print('date is ${date.toString()}');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: FlatButton(
          onPressed: () {selectDate(context);},
          child: Text('calendar'),
          color: Colors.blue,
        ));
  }
}
```

Note I've removed static in front of date as presumably you will want to change the date and static members are not accessible through currentState. If you don't need date to ever be anything other than DateTime.now() then you probably don't need to access the widget state and can just refer to DateTime.now() directly from the other widget.

Comment: where i am gonna define the global key?

Comment: in your main.dart file after the imports and before the void main(){}.

Comment: ok , when i am trying to define it it says MyCalendar doesn't extend 'State<StatefulWidget>'.
Try using a type that is or is a subclass of 'State<StatefulWidget> why that is coming?

Comment: I think you are defining the key as "GlobalKey<MyCalendar>()" whereas it should be "GlobalKey<_MyCalendarState>()"

Comment: i changed it but it could not recognize it although i imported the location but says `the name '_MyCalendarState' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument.
Try correcting the name to an existing type, or defining a type named '_MyCalendarState `  but when i changed it to` GlobalKey<State<MyCalendar>>` but when i implemented that i can not recognize class properties and does not show the properties

Comment: is the file where you have the _MyCalendarState imported by main.dart?

Comment: it is in main.dart i tried it in after and before the mail. function still doesn't work :)

Comment: main function* spelling mistake

Comment: hmmm...hard to say then - can you maybe post more of the code, ideally the minimal version of main.dart that produces this error message?

Comment: based on the main.dart you posted the class _MyCalendarState is not in main.dart it seems? And the GlobalKey type is not class _MyCalendarState either. I think it should work if you set the key type to class _MyCalendarState and then place the class _MyCalendarState class in a file that is imported by main.dart or in main.dart itself

Comment: thank you very much for you efforts and time sir , it works

Answer (score -1):

```
class MyCalendar extends StatefulWidget {
 DateTime date = DateTime.now();
      @override
      _MyCalendarState createState() => _MyCalendarState();
    }
```

and in `_MyCalendarState` use `widget.date`