# Flutter divide single page in 2 parts and use navigation only in 1 part

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, flutter-image

In flutter web, I am trying to divide my screen into 2 parts. One would be static and 1 would be loaded dynamically. Is there a way to apply navigation only in 1 section instead of on changing the entire page.

So based on the values selected in 1st section, 2nd section can show a new Page.

Comment: Check this out,it answered most of my questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66690100/navigate-part-of-screen-from-drawer

Answer (score 1):

You can use another [`Navigator`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator-class.html) in your dynamic section.

Consult the [Flutter cookbook](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/effects/nested-nav) for detailed instructions.

Comment: But that changes the entire page

Comment: It does not. It only changes the widget you wrap the `Navigator` with.