# Survey_kit with Flutter / Dart. How to get CurrentStep

Tags: flutter, dart

I am writing a survey using Flutter for Web and a library called survey_kit.
I need to get the value of the CurrentStep to display a relevant image which changes as a the image navigates through the survey.

In the docs there is a class called *PresentingSurveyState* with property CurrentStep.

Can someone post an example how to access it ?
Any help greatly appreciated!
pk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the library but the usual method you have to access such states is via keys:

Where you instantiate the widget `PresentingSurvey` you create a key such as: `GlobalKey<PresentingSurveyState>` and you pass it to the widget:

```
...
final myPresentingKey = GlobalKey<PresentingSurveyState>();
...

PresentingSurvey{
 key: myPresentingKey
...
}
...
```

At that point you have access to the state via the key

You can also have a look at this similar answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46545141/11187075