# Calling the function we defined in a statefull widget class when a notification comes to the phone

Tags: flutter, function, dart, state-management

I want to call the function we defined in a stateful widget class when a notification comes to the phone, so I need to use it in another class.

For example:

```
class ContactListPage extends StatefulWidget {
   @override
   _ContactListPageState createState() => _ContactListPageState();
}

class _ContactListPageState extends State<ContactListPage>{

     doSomething(){
         print("do something");
     }

}
-------------------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------

class PushMessageManager {
  configureNotificationsActions() async {
     FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

       if (remoteMessage.data.isNotEmpty) {

         if (remoteMessage.data["type"] == "message") {

             // ContactListPage.doSomething();
         }
       }
     }
}
```

I tried calling directly, but I couldn't get what I wanted. What method should I use? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Should function `doSomething` perform any visual activity (show "Add contact" page etc.) or just do something in backgrond?

Comment: should send a request to the server and update my contact list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `_ContactListPageState` is private (as indicated by the `_`, so you won't be able to see the function.

If you want to call a method in the state of a `StatefulWidget`, you can use a `GlobalKey`, like in this other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46545141/15469537

Steps:

1. Make the `_ContactListPageState` public (refactor it to remove the `_`)
2. Make sure all fields in the State you don't want to make public are private (start with `_`)
3. Create a `GlobalKey` in a main/parent Widget (which you can use in your message handler)

```dart
final contactListPageKey = GlobalKey<ContactListPageState>();

// pass it as key to the contact list page
return ContactListPage(key: contactListPageKey);
```

4. Use this key to access the state

```dart
if (remoteMessage.data["type"] == "message") {
  // call doSomething if the state exists. 
  // Since the key is Global, you cannot have the page open twice
  contactListPageKey.currentState?.doSomething();
}
```

Note that if the Widget is not mounted, this will not call the function at all, so make sure to think about the different possible states of the app when the message is received.

#### Recommendation

It's recommended to have a global/static function to handle notifications which can, for instance, store something in the `SharedPreferences` so that the rest of the app has access to it when needed.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to use [event_bus](https://pub.dev/packages/event_bus) to achieve what you want.

demo code:

```
class PushEvent{}

class ContactListPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ContactListPageState createState() => _ContactListPageState();
}

class _ContactListPageState extends State<ContactListPage>{

  late final StreamSubscription<PushEvent> _subscription;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _subscription = EventBus().on<PushEvent>().listen((event) {
      doSomething();
    });
  }

  doSomething(){
    print("do something");
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _subscription.cancel();
  }

}

class PushMessageManager {
  configureNotificationsActions() async {
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

      if (remoteMessage.data.isNotEmpty) {

        if (remoteMessage.data["type"] == "message") {
          EventBus().fire(PushEvent());
          // ContactListPage.doSomething();
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```